# Specialize the base's templated member function in derived class

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

**TL;DR;**

Compiling the following code ends with two unresolved externals.

**QUESTION**

Is there a way to have an undefined templated member function inside a base class and have that function partially specialized in a derived classe so the partial specialization would be restricted to the derived class it was defined in?

**EXPLANATION**

As you can see both `serial_port` and `liquid_crystal` is derived from the `stream` base class. The `stream` class will provide an uniform interface to send text to different peripherals. Every class which is derived from `stream` has to implement the `print(char)` function which will handle the low level communication with the peripheral. Apart from that, there is an undefined, templated version of print which can be specialized to any custom type the user might want to print.

The `stream` class has a templated definition of `operator <<` which is used to write data into the stream. This operator would call `stream::print` which would handle the actual printing. As you can see `print(const char*)` and `print(fill)` is already defined because I want them present in every derived class from `stream`.

*Now here comes the part which introduces the error*

The peripherals I want to communicate with have some basic commands (LCD: move cursor to x,y coordinates, serial port: set baud rate to x) which are not interchangeable between them meaning the LCD doesn't know how to change the baud rate and the serial port doesn't have a cursor which could be moved to specific coordinates. I want to pass the commands through the `operator <<` just like I did with `fill`. Every command would be an new struct holding the required data for the command and there would be a specialized version of `print` to handle each of them.

This works in theory but fails during compiling because the specialized version of `print` is defined in the derived class but the `operator <<` is defined in the `stream` class. When I pass the commands to the stream the linker looks for a specialized definition of `print` inside `stream` and of course it fails because those simply aren't there.

How could I overcome this error?
I'm using Visual Studio 15 Preview 4 and I didn't change any compiler flags.

**SOURCE CODE**

```
#include <iostream>

class stream
{
public:
    struct fill
    {
        int n;
        char ch;
    };

    stream()
    {}

    virtual ~stream()
    {}

    template <typename T>
    stream& operator << (T t)
    {
        this->print(t);
        return *this;
    }

protected:
    virtual void print(char) = 0;

    template <typename T>
    void print(T);
};

template <>
void stream::print<const char*>(const char* str)
{
    while (*str != '\0')
        this->print(*(str++));
}

template <>
void stream::print<stream::fill>(stream::fill f)
{
    while (f.n > 0)
    {
        this->print(f.ch);
        f.n--;
    }
}

class serial_port : public stream
{
public:
    struct set_baudrate
    {
        int baud;
    };

    using stream::stream;

private:
    void print(char c) override
    {
        // TODO: print to the actual serial port
        std::cout << c;
    }

    template <typename T>
    void print(T t)
    {
        stream::print<T>(t);
    }
};

template <>
void serial_port::print<serial_port::set_baudrate>(serial_port::set_baudrate)
{
    this->print("set_baudrate");
}

class liquid_crystal : public stream
{
public:
    struct move
    {
        int x;
        int y;
    };

    using stream::stream;

private:
    void print(char c) override
    {
        // TODO: print to a character LCD
        std::cout << c;
    }

    template <typename T>
    void print(T t)
    {
        stream::print<T>(t);
    }
};


template <>
void liquid_crystal::print<liquid_crystal::move>(liquid_crystal::move)
{
    this->print("move");
}

int main()
{
    liquid_crystal lcd;
    lcd << liquid_crystal::move{ 1, 2 };
    serial_port serial;
    serial << serial_port::set_baudrate{ 9600 };
}
```

**EDIT**

The problem is more visible looking at the [compiler output](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/94a0f9dc4673f8f9), the linker is looking for `void stream::print<liquid_crystal::move>(liquid_crystal::move)` and `void stream::print<serial_port::set_baudrate>(serial_port::set_baudrate)` but the function signatures should be `void liquid_crystal::print<liquid_crystal::move>(liquid_crystal::move)` and `void serial_port::print<serial_port::set_baudrate>(serial_port::set_baudrate)`.

Comment: What compiler and flags are you using? Not [these](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4db50d669de63da9).

Comment: I will edit the post immediately

Comment: @LogicStuff I updated my question and the source code. [Here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/94a0f9dc4673f8f9) is the compiler output and now it's producing the same error as in VS.

Comment: Hmm... GCC makes it clear that the problem is in `operator<<()`, which makes it a bit easier to narrow down: `In function \`stream& stream::operator<< <liquid_crystal::move>(liquid_crystal::move)':                       
main.cpp:(.text._ZN6streamlsIN14liquid_crystal4moveEEERS_T_[_ZN6streamlsIN14liquid_crystal4moveEEERS_T_]+0x1f): undefined reference to \`void stream::print<liquid_crystal::move>(liquid_crystal::move)'`

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there a reason you can't make some manipulator functions that can be passed to `operator<<`, similarly to `std::endl()`?

Comment: I could specialize `stream::print<T>` but then commands for LCD would be usable for serial port and vice versa which is not desired.

Answer (score 0):

In `main`, the line:

```
lcd << liquid_crystal::move{ 1, 2 };
```

calls:

```
stream::operator<< <liquid_crystal::move>(liquid_crystal::move)
```

which then calls:

```
stream::print<liquid_crystal::move>(liquid_crystal::move)
```

but the `stream::print` function is defined only for the `const char*` and `stream::fill` types.

The `liquid_crystal::print` function is not used, because it is not an override of the `stream::print` (it is shadowing the `stream::print` in `liquid_crystal` class). In order to access it from `stream` using `this` (which is a `stream*`, not a `liquid_crystal*`), the `stream::print` would have to be virtual. But in this case, that is not possible, because it is a template function.

In general, a solution for *virtual template functions* design issue is usually not simple. But in this specific case, the simplest approach might be replicating the `operator<<` in each derived class. However, it won't work in cases where the `stream::operator<<` is called, such as:

```
void func(stream& s) {
    s << liquid_crystal::move{ 1, 2 };
}
int main() {
    liquid_crystal lcd;
    func(lcd);
}
```

Comment: Indeed. I'm going to try to solve this problem using a different approach. I have a feeling that this code will only become uglier.

Comment: Agreed.  It's possible to make it work as is with a little SFINAE magic, but if you're not careful, that also leads to insanity such as `serial << liquid_crystal::move{ 1, 2 };` being valid.  I'm trying to think of a way around this, but everything I can think of would involve either defining `operator<<()` in child classes anyways (rendering the SFINAE moot) or require determining dynamic type of `*this` at runtime (which generally indicates a problem with the code).

Answer (score 0):

The optimal solution would be for each class to define `operator<<` on its own.  If this isn't possible, however, SFINAE and dynamic casting can be abused to achieve the desired effect.

**I do *not* recommend using this in your final product**.  I merely post it here in the hopes that someone more knowledgeable than I can find a way to make this work without `dynamic_cast`, without introducing code that can potentially cause undefined behaviour.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

// -----

// void_t definition.  If your compiler has provisional C++17 support, this may already be
//  available.
template<typename...>
struct make_void { using type = void; };

template<typename... T>
using void_t = typename make_void<T...>::type;

// -----

// SFINAE condition: Is argument a stream command?

class stream;

template<typename T, typename = void>
struct is_stream_command : std::false_type
{};

template<typename T>
struct is_stream_command<T, void_t<typename T::command_for>> :
    std::integral_constant<bool, std::is_base_of<stream, typename T::command_for>::value ||
                                 std::is_same<stream, typename T::command_for>::value>
{};

// -----

class stream
{
public:
    // Stream command type.  Used as parent class for actual commands.
    // Necessary for version of print() that handles stream commands.
    // Not needed for SFINAE.
    // If used, each command will need a constructor.
    struct command
    {
        using command_for = stream;
        // This typedef should be defined in each command, as the containing class.
        // If command is valid for multiple classes, this should be their parent class.
        // Used for SFINAE.

        virtual ~command() = default;
    };

    struct fill : command
    {
        int n;
        char ch;
        using command_for = stream;

        fill(int n, char ch) : n(n), ch(ch) {}
    };

    stream()
    {}

    virtual ~stream()
    {}

    // Called for stream commands.  Solves the issue you were having, but introduces a
    //  different issue: It casts "this", which can cause problems.
    // Tied with a version of stream::print() that handles commands.
    template<typename T>
    typename std::enable_if<is_stream_command<T>::value, stream&>::type
    operator<<(T t)
    {
        static_cast<typename T::command_for*>(this)->print((stream::command*) &t);
        return *this;
    }

    // Called for other output.
    template<typename T>
    typename std::enable_if<!is_stream_command<T>::value, stream&>::type
    operator<<(T t)
    {
        this->print(t);
        return *this;
    }

protected:
    virtual void print(char) = 0;

    virtual void print(stream::command* com);

    template <typename T>
    void print(T);
};

template <>
void stream::print<const char*>(const char* str)
{
    while (*str != '\0')
        this->print(*(str++));

    std::cout << std::endl; // For testing.
}

template <>
void stream::print<stream::fill>(stream::fill f)
{
    std::cout << "fill "; // For testing.

    while (f.n > 0)
    {
        this->print(f.ch);
        f.n--;
    }

    std::cout << std::endl; // For testing.
}

// Version of print() which handles stream commands.
// Solves problem introduced by operator<<() for commands, but introduces its own problem:
//  dynamic casting.
void stream::print(stream::command* com) {
    if (dynamic_cast<stream::fill*>(com)) {
        std::cout << "Valid command: "; // For testing.
        this->print(*(dynamic_cast<stream::fill*>(com)));
    } else {
        // Handle as appropriate.
        std::cout << "Invalid command." << std::endl;
    }
}

// -----

class serial_port : public stream
{
public:
    struct set_baudrate : stream::command
    {
        int baud;
        using command_for = serial_port;

        set_baudrate(int baud) : baud(baud) {}
    };

    using stream::stream;

private:
    void print(char c) override
    {
        // TODO: print to the actual serial port
        std::cout << c;
    }
    void print(stream::command* com) override;

    template <typename T>
    void print(T t)
    {
        stream::print<T>(t);
    }

    // Necessary to allow stream::operator<<() to call private member function print().
    template<typename T>
    friend typename std::enable_if<is_stream_command<T>::value, stream&>::type
    stream::operator<<(T t);
};

template <>
void serial_port::print<serial_port::set_baudrate>(serial_port::set_baudrate)
{
    this->print("set_baudrate");
}

void serial_port::print(stream::command* com) {
    if (dynamic_cast<serial_port::set_baudrate*>(com)) {
        std::cout << "Valid command: "; // For testing.
        this->print(*(dynamic_cast<serial_port::set_baudrate*>(com)));
    } else {
        // Invalid commands fall through to parent class, in case they're valid for any
        //  stream.
        this->stream::print(com);
    }
}

// -----

class liquid_crystal : public stream
{
public:
    struct move : stream::command
    {
        int x;
        int y;
        using command_for = liquid_crystal;

        move(int x, int y) : x(x), y(y) {}
    };

    using stream::stream;

private:
    void print(char c) override
    {
        // TODO: print to a character LCD
        std::cout << c;
    }
    void print(stream::command* com) override;

    template <typename T>
    void print(T t)
    {
        stream::print<T>(t);
    }


    // Necessary to allow stream::operator<<() to call private member function print().
    template<typename T>
    friend typename std::enable_if<is_stream_command<T>::value, stream&>::type
    stream::operator<<(T t);
};

template <>
void liquid_crystal::print<liquid_crystal::move>(liquid_crystal::move)
{
    this->print("move");
}

void liquid_crystal::print(stream::command* com) {
    if (dynamic_cast<liquid_crystal::move*>(com)) {
        std::cout << "Valid command: "; // For testing.
        this->print(*(dynamic_cast<liquid_crystal::move*>(com)));
    } else {
        // Invalid commands fall through to parent class, in case they're valid for any
        //  stream.
        this->stream::print(com);
    }
}

// -----

int main()
{
    liquid_crystal lcd;
    lcd << 'a' << " " << liquid_crystal::move{ 1, 2 };
    serial_port serial;
    serial << 'a' << " " << serial_port::set_baudrate{ 9600 };

    std::cout << "Are they valid commands?" << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::boolalpha;
    std::cout << "stream::fill, for serial_port: ";
    serial << stream::fill{ 3, 'a' };
    std::cout << "stream::fill, for liquid_crystal: ";
    lcd << stream::fill{ 3, 'a' };

    std::cout << "serial_port::set_baudrate, for serial_port: ";
    serial << serial_port::set_baudrate{ 9600 };
    std::cout << "serial_port::set_baudrate, for liquid_crystal: ";
    lcd << serial_port::set_baudrate{ 9600 };

    std::cout << "liquid_crystal::move, for serial_port: ";
    serial << liquid_crystal::move{ 1, 2 };
    std::cout << "liquid_crystal::move, for liquid_crystal: ";
    lcd << liquid_crystal::move{ 1, 2 };
}
```

This will have the following output:

```
a b
Valid command: move
a b
Valid command: set_baudrate
Are they valid commands?
stream::fill, for serial_port: Valid command: fill aaa
stream::fill, for liquid_crystal: Valid command: fill aaa
serial_port::set_baudrate, for serial_port: Valid command: set_baudrate
serial_port::set_baudrate, for liquid_crystal: Invalid command.
liquid_crystal::move, for serial_port: Invalid command.
liquid_crystal::move, for liquid_crystal: Valid command: move
```

I don't like this solution, due to it relying on `dynamic_cast`.  However, I find that a faulty solution is often better than no solution, as it can help lead you to a *good* solution.  This solves the linking issue, and can ideally be used as a basis for a solution that doesn't need any casting.